# Why is C allocating memory for printf on heap?

Tags: c, printf, valgrind

Using valgrind I run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    printf("Hello World!");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The valgrind output is:

```
 HEAP SUMMARY:
 ==22613==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==22613==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
```

Why does the printf statement allocate 1,024 bytes on the heap?

Comment: Does it allocate anything if you do `fprintf(stdout, "Hello Wolrd!\n");`?

Comment: Yes, I get the same result...

Comment: Nope, in that case there are 0 allocations. Is there a way to see what is allocated, or more info with valgrind?

Comment: I can't reproduce this! I noticed a few days ago that `puts()` allocated some bytes, but `printf()` doesn't. Are you linking to some library?

Comment: So the whole test.c file is the code you see above, I'm running it on the Uni's machine

Comment: Maybe the string literal is stored in the heap?

Comment: @JohnColeman It allocated 1024 bytes.

Comment: @Daniel, What about compilation flags? What if you do `gcc -S` and check what is being generated really? `printf()` is in general a complex function, but printing a string literal should not generate something too complicated I guess.

Comment: I stand corrected, In fact, I can see exactly the same behavior.

Comment: 1024 seems like overkill for whatever it is doing, like it is allocating more space than is needed.

Comment: I tried it with a much longer string, same amount or memory allocated.

Comment: Here's the -S http://pastebin.com/JAftTirW

Comment: First, did you try without the printf? It could also be the runtime library setup for `main()` doing the allocation; maybe making a copy of the environment. If it really is printf, it's probably allocating an initial buffer for format expansion. But these are just guesses. Do some work: get the source for your C library including the printf you're using. Study it to find what's happening. You'll learn something.

Comment: Same with extremely long str. I did try without printf, no issue then. How do I get the library C source?

Comment: the total allocation grows and the # of allocs increases.

Comment: @Daniel
printf: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/printf.c
vfprintf: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c

Comment: @Jerry Thanks for the code.  Some execution paths definitely do allocate a block of dynamic memory and do what essentially amounts to calling a backend equivalent to `vsprintf()` to interpret the format string, and then printing the buffer.  E.g. the line `return buffered_vfprintf (s, format, ap);` One reason to keep the buffer around might be so that you can still print an error message if you run out of memory.